# How to store data from Axios response?

Tags: reactjs, axios, state, use-state

I'm trying to store axios response but approach 1 seems to be the only one that works.

**Approach 1: works ok from state**

```
const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      await axios
        .get("sampleApi")
        .then((response) => {
          setData(response.data);
          setLoadingData(false);
        });
    }
    if (loadingData) {
          getData();
        }
      }, []);

    ...

// This works fine from state
          {data.map(
              (i, index) => {
                return <p key={index}>{i.id}</p>
          }
        )}
```

**Approach 2: Attempting setting as a regular variable instead of state**

```
const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = useState(true);
  let data;


  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      await axios
        .get("sampleApi")
        .then((response) => {
          data = response.data // <====== This 
          setLoadingData(false);
        });
    }
    if (loadingData) {
          getData();
        }
      }, []);

    ...

// Following results in: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
          {data.map(
              (i, index) => {
                return <p key={index}>{i.id}</p>
          }
        )}
```

So, two questions:

1. Is it "bad practice" to store data in the state (as I only plan to read it and not modify it)
2. Any idea what am I doing wrong in approach 2?

Comment: There is no problem I think. I use it inside my own library [react-axios-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-axios-api), and it's used too in `redux-toolkit`....

Comment: please check this link for Question 2 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56155959/what-does-it-mean-to-move-this-variable-directly-inside-useeffect-in-this-erro

I am getting this error : 
Assignments to the 'data' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)eslint

Comment: I think approach 2 is anti pattern. Approach 1 right.. this is what the state is for

Answer (score 2):

> Is it "bad practice" to store data in the state

No, this is what the state is for.

> (as I only plan to read it and not modify it)

You are modifying it: You are changing it from the default value to the value from the HTTP request.

> Any idea what am I doing wrong in approach 2?

That is [a FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)