# how to reload data from server using react navigation tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I wanted to reload data from the server ever time a certain tab is tapped on. useEffect was however not doing this by itself as I expected it would. I found [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect) however

which seems to do what I want.

```
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      request(uid);
      return () => {
        alert("Screen was unfocused");
        // Do something when the screen is unfocused
        // Useful for cleanup functions
      };
    }, [])
  );
```

So, this works great in that every time I tap on that tab it fetches the data like I want. However, in the example code it has the 'useful for cleanup functions'. Is there something I should be doing there? I am basically fetching a list of users.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54954385/8839059) answer your question?

Comment: I don't know. It depends if the answer is that I need to put some sort of abort controller or cancellation token in there?

Comment: Yes. If your component unmounts before completing the fetch request, you are 1) making an useless fetch; and 2) trying to update an unmounted component. So you should use this `return` to abort your request

Comment: Okay, I just have to figure out what to put in there now though as I am using ApiSauce which is a wrapper for Axios.