# why React not logging the error when setting state on unmounted component when returning cleanup function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When setting state after a component was unmounted, React **should log** the following error:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

However, If I'm returning an empty function as the cleanup function it would **not** log the error.

the code:

```
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

function Comp() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("nothing");

  useEffect(() => {
    setState("loading");

    sleep(1000).then(() => {
      console.log("setting state");
      setState("finished");
    });

    // When the below return exists it does not log the error
    return () => {};
  }, []);

  return <span>{state}</span>;
}

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    sleep(500).then(() => setShow(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        <button onClick={() => setShow((v) => !v)}>Show</button>
        {show && <Comp />}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-brook-e35rpe?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: The issue here is that you are using an async function inside of the useEffect hook. If the promise isn't resolved before the component unmounts you will get this error. The cleanup function is similar to the old 'componentWillUnmount' function which will execute only after the logic inside of your hook (componentDidMount) is executed. I know the docs can get confusing with this so here is a good article on this. Hope it helps! https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-react-useeffect-cleanup-function/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React useEffect causing: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954385/react-useeffect-causing-cant-perform-a-react-state-update-on-an-unmounted-comp)

Comment: Thank you but this is actually the opposite as I expect it to log but it won't

Comment: Good question! Worth mentioning: It _does_ warn for (a.) class components, and (b.) components one level deeper, e.g. `{ show && <div><Comp /></div> }` or `{ show && <CompContainer /> }` with `function CompContainer() { return <Comp /> }`

Comment: I think I might have found the condition that prevents the warning for non-nested functional components: [PassiveUnmountPendingDev](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v17.0.2/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberWorkLoop.old.js#L3066).

Comment: Apparently that warning will be removed soon: [Pullrequest #22114](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22114), [commit 7ed0706d](https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/7ed0706d) is already merged. (but not yet in current verion v17.0.2)